# iOS CI - RestKit error lcl_RK.h file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, continuous-integration, restkit

We're running an Xcode server to perform continuous integration (CI) on our projects. This works quite well even with projects having Cocoapods dependencies. Actually we're running a pre-script to obtain all the dependencies and integrate them.

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
if [ ! -e "$HOME/.cocoapods/repos/myRepo" ]
then
pod repo add myRepo https://user:password@our.server/git/MyRepoSpecs.git
fi
cd ${XCS_SOURCE_DIR}/MyCoolProject
git submodule update --init --recursive 
pod update
```

Now it's doing the checkout as it does locally, but it fails with the following errors

> In file included from
>   /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/86993548ff870d5e9d3b320316078a8e/Source/Knowledge/Pods/RestKit/Code/CoreData/NSManagedObject+RKAdditions.m:11:
>   /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/86993548ff870d5e9d3b320316078a8e/Source/Knowledge/Pods/RestKit/Code/Support/RKLog.h:27:9:
>   fatal error: 'lcl_RK.h' file not found
>
> ## import "lcl_RK.h"
>
> ```
>     ^ 1 error generated.
> ```

Which I never get locally.

Somebody succeed to do continuous integration with RestKit and Cocoapods?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, a "file not found" on integration that doesn't happen locally. It's not a cocoapod, but a framework we created, and actually it had problems recognizing the file at first. But this project does have cocoapods and a script like yours to integrate them, so maybe that's creating interference. Will watch and hope someone has an answer.

Comment: Why aren't you using pod install?

Comment: @Wain Initially we had an additional step that was checking if we need ```pod install```, however due to this comment we removed it: 
https://github.com/CocoaPods/blog.cocoapods.org/issues/21#issuecomment-99940183

Comment: I have CI setup to work from a clean folder each build, check out the code, pod install and build - works well. Does your log say anything else failed earlier?

Comment: @Wain Actually there is no difference in this case. You could even use pod update and get the correct results. I've projects running on this system without RestKit being involved that work perfectly. I've just a problem when I add RestKit

Comment: Yeah, I'm just outlining what I have working with RestKit. The only time I have issues is when there's a network problem during setup for a build when some repos aren't downloaded...

Comment: Now I tried to clean it up and switch to ```pod install```but got the same result again